# Are logical bitwise operators any use?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I'm just a learner at Java, and I'm at the bitwise operators part of my teachings. Wondering when on Earth would I use these???? Why would you want to change numbers in that fashion like moving the digets left <<< ?? Thanks for your time, detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried *any* sort of research? What have you found?

Comment: Why don't you click on the tag you have chosen ([tag:bitwise-operators]) and see what kind of questions people ask about them? And what answers they are given?

Comment: Google: parity, CRC, Hamming weight,....

Comment: Heck. Copy/paste your own question title to Google as it is. It will lead you to a SO-site full of examples.

Comment: Google "efficient integer multiplication/division"; "bit masks"; "bit fields"; "flag bits"; "hashcode dispersion", ...

Comment: There is lots of technical use, for example when you create a hash code, want to maintain a bit-field (compact representation of flags). But I somewhat agree: it is not the best topic to start programming with.

Answer (score 0):

There are many usecase for bitwise operators. One of the more common ones is [bitmasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) - a technique to set several "flags" on a single integer. A good example from the JDK itself is the flags set when compiling a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
Pattern p = 
    Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]\s\n", Pattern.UNIX_LINES | Pattern.CANON_EQ);
```